# How to connect to the Internet using an Airtel 3G USB dongle?

Tags: internet, 3g

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an HP pavilion dv6 laptop alongside Windows 7.

I am not able to connect to internet via Airtel 3G USB dongle. I tried editing the network connection and am still unable to connect to Internet. Apart from that, while installing Ubuntu certain firmware updates we needed and I skipped that step since I couldn't connect to Internet.

Comment: Its very simple. All you need to do is to insert the dongle in the USB port. Once you insert the dongle you can get internet connection.

Comment: For me, I need to connect it twice, connect and wait for few seconds and then remove the USB and connect it again
then you may be have to open http://192.168.1.1/

Answer (score 3):

Here is how it worked for me:

Properly insert your dongle to the USB port; don't worry if it's not detected by Ubuntu.
Go to: Network Connection -> Mobile Broadband -> Add

Now there are 5 simple steps; select the natural options:

1. Select appropriate mobile device (for me, Huawei)
2. Choose country provider/region (for me, India)
3. Choose your provider (for me, Airtel)
4. Choose your Billing Plan (for me, Default)
5. Confirm Mobile broadband settings (confirm)

Since in my case it was without password, I din't have to do any extra settings related to ip address or any setting in the final dialog.

Answer (score 0):

First connect to some LAN or Wi-Fi and update your packages. Then, when you plugin the dongle, the network connections should show Enable Mobile Broadband. Then click on Edit connections -> Mobile Broadband -> add. Select country, then operator and so on. Try this and get back.

This has worked for my Reliance 3G Dongle.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the install_linux folder from the usb dongle to your desktop and then run the installer script

```
cd ~/Desktop/install_linux
chmod +x ./install_linux
sudo ./install_linux
```

Taken from: http://www.tuxtrix.com/2013/06/how-to-install-airtel-mobile-broadband.html