# How to install 3G dongles on Ubuntu 12?

Tags: internet

I just bought an unlocked Idea 3G Netsetter dongle (USB stick for internet connection) and have an Aircel SIM (3G activated on unlimited plan). I cnnnected my SIM properly with dongle.

Nothing happened!

Please tell me how to install it. I am using Ubuntu 12 with Windows XP (installed using Wubi).

P.S It's detecting on Windows but not on Ubuntu.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Try to access the contents of the Dongle by mounting it. You will definitely find some README and script that will do the job of installing the drivers on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for reply :)

I am new to Ubuntu. How to mount it (it's even not detecting the dongle; whereas; Windows XP do).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138253/i-am-not-able-to-connect-to-internet-via-airtel-3g-usb-dongle?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

- Insert your usbmodem.
- Click on the network icon on the Right Side > Edit Connection > Select Mobile Broadband > Add
- Follow the steps (select country and your service provider as Aircel). complete the steps by saving.
- Click on the desktop taskbar network icon and select the connection made.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a Dlink DWM 156 Modem to connect to internet using your Aricel 3G Sim try to follow the instructions on this link it worked for me.

http://lawrencematthew.wordpress.com/2013/06/21/connecting-ubuntu-12-04-2-to-internet-using-d-link-dwm-156-3g3-75g-usb-modem/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.